# Uniqueness of TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql, triggered-send

I'm trying to create an automation that will report on the performance of certain metrics for emails that belong to a Journey. What I want to know is how unique is TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID when it comes to identifying each email? As in, if I have journey email called `JourneyEmailA` that gets sent 5000 times during last week, when I go to the _Job data view, will there be as many different TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID or just one code repeated 5000 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TriggeredsendDefinitionobjectID (The object ID for the triggered send definition) will stay the same for the version of the Journey. on the _job dataview you will see only one row per jobid (if you republish the email activity it will get a new jobid).

If you want subscriber level detail, you would use the _SENT dataview, to see the 5000 rows